# Joining 3 or more tables yields duplicate tuples

Tags: java, mysql

Table structure:

```
checklist
---------
id, unit_id, tech_id, date
1,  1,       1,       10/16/2018
2,  2,       2,       10/16/2018 


units
-------
unit_id, unit_name
1,       52
2,       21

techs
--------
tech_id, tech_name
1,       John
2,       Smith
```

Checklist has foreign key constraints, a delete restrict and update cascade for both `unit_id` and `tech_id`

The query that doesn't work:

```
SELECT units.unit_number, checklist.date, techs.tech_name 
FROM checklist
join units on checklist.unit_id 
join techs on checklist.tech_id
```

Results:

```
unit_name, tech_name, date
--------------------------
52,        John,      10/16/2018
52,        John,      10/16/2018
52,        John,      10/16/2018
52,        John,      10/16/2018
21,        Smith,      10/16/2018
21,        Smith,      10/16/2018
21,        Smith,      10/16/2018
21,        Smith,      10/16/2018
```

I am not sure why I have duplicate tuples, can someone explain why this is happening and how to correct my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join a column to a column as below:

```
SELECT units.unit_number, checklist.date, techs.tech_name 
FROM checklist c
join units u on c.unit_id = u.unit_id
join techs t on c.tech_id = t.tech_id
```